# How to fix NameError, Tk() not defined

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.8

I'm trying to use tkinter in Pycharm but it does not work.

```
from tkinter import *

fenster = Tk()

fenster.title("Fenster")

fenster.mainloop()`
```

It also does not work on the terminal, because the error "NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined" occurs.

The `tkinter._test()` works fine the terminal.

Comment: Did you name your file `tkinter.py`, then change it

Answer (score 0):

you should not name your file with the same name as your library. in this case change your file name to something else to solve the error.

Comment: Are you a wizard?:D